# Free Windows app to Un-RAR with lots of <file>.rNN files

Tags: windows, gratis, archiving

Should be obvious, but I cant remember it.

I found an old Widows directory with an ambiguous name and two sub-directories "Cd1" and "Cd2", each of which contains one `abcd.rar` file and lots of `abcd.r01`, `abcd.r02` ... files.

Which app do I need to extract from this/these archive(s)?  Windows, please, and gratis.

Comment: What did you try / find sofar ? Didn't test but maybe 7Zip?

Comment: That's just a spanned / multi-volume rar archive.

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=RAR_(file_format)&oldid=826919621#Third_party_software_for_extracting_RAR_files :

- RARLAB distributes the C++ source code and binaries for a command-line "unrar" program.[15] The license freely permits its use to produce software capable of unpacking, but not creating, RAR archives, but it is not an unrestricted free software license.
- 7-Zip, a free and open source program, starting from 7-Zip version 15.06 beta[16] can unpack RAR5 archives, using the RARLAB unrar code.
- PeaZip is a free software RAR unarchiver for Windows, licensed under the LGPL, it also runs as RAR extractor on Linux and BSD, with GUI. PeaZip supports both pre-RAR5 .rar files, and files in new RAR5 format (out of the box). It can also install UNRAR5 Plugin based on royalty-free but not OSI-compliant RARLAB's unrar as alternative engine to handle RAR5 format.
- The Unarchiver is a free software unarchiver for RAR and other formats, licensed under the LGPL. It runs on macOS and the command line version, unar, also runs on Windows and Linux. It supports all versions of the RAR archive format including RAR3 and RAR5.[17][18][19]
- UNRARLIB (UniquE RAR File Library),[20] an older version of the unrar source was the basis for an obsolete free software unarchiving library called "unrarlib", licensed under the GPL. It could only decompress archives created by RAR versions prior to 2.9; archives created by RAR 2.9 and later use different formats not supported by this library. The original development team ended work on this library in 2007.

Otherwise, you can use WinRAR  [WinRAR](https://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) (non-free).